# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Post Hook not returning document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Summary**

I'm trying to return the updated document in a post findOneAndUpdate hook in Mongoose.  I know how it behaves and it doesn't typically return the updated document but I'm passing { new: true } with my findOneAndUpdate.

**Error**

The error I'm getting is that doc is undefined in my post hook.  It's defined for the "code that works" but when I use the actual findOneAndUpdate operation I want to, doc becomes undefined.  I think it's because I'm trying to update a nested object in the document but I still need to be able to update the nested object and use the post hook somehow

**Mongoose Model**

```
const apiTestArray = {
  apiName: { type: String, require: false },
  startStats: {
    seasonStats: { type: Object, require: false },
    lifeStats: { type: Object, require: false }
  },
  endingStats: {
    seasonStats: { type: Object, require: false },
    lifeStats: { type: Object, require: false }
  },
  startTime: { type: Date, require: false },
  endTime: { type: Date, require: true },
  completed: { type: Boolean, require: false }
};

const apiTestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  apiTests: [apiTestArray],
  completed: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: false }
});
```

**Code that works**

```
const findOneAndUpdate = await ApiTest.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: inProgressTest._id },
      {
        $set: { completed: true } 
      },
      { new: true }
    );

apiTestSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function(doc, next) {
  console.log("post hook ran");
  // console.log("this", this);
  console.log("apiTest", doc);
  doc.completed = doc.apiTests.some(apiTest => apiTest.completed);
  // doc.save().then(next());
});
```

**Desired Code that doesn't work**

```
const findOneAndUpdate = await ApiTest.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: inProgressTest._id, "apiTests.$.apiName": scoutVersion },
      {
        $set: {
          "apiTests.$.completed": true,
          "apiTests.$.endingStats": newStats,
          "apiTests.$.endTime": endTime
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    );

apiTestSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function(doc, next) {
  doc.completed = doc.apiTests.some(apiTest => apiTest.completed);
  // doc.save().then(next());
});
```